# SQl Server Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have database with more than `30 tables` and more than **270k records in one table** (the most important table) and create view get data from this table and other tables,

When I run the code below on my machine it takes **less than 4 sec** to get data from the view.

> select * from view

**My problem is that,**

When I run the same script of database on another machine and run the same query from the view it takes a very long time.

**Code for view**

```
SELECT
    dbo.UserSite.UserId,
    dbo.UserSite.Name,
    dbo.Site.RootPageURL,
    dbo.PDFDocument.DocumentId,
    dbo.RunDocumentVerificationResult.Status,
    dbo.UserSite.UserSiteId,
    dbo.Systemcode.Value,
    dbo.RunDocumentVerificationResult.PageNumber,
    dbo.RunDocumentVerificationResult.TestNameID,
    dbo.RunDocumentVerificationResult.VerificationResultID,
    dbo.TaskRun.VerificationEndDate,
    dbo.TaskRun.RunId,
    dbo.RunDocument.IsTagged,
    dbo.RunDocument.IsProtected,
    dbo.RunDocument.IsCorrupted
FROM
    dbo.UserSite
INNER JOIN dbo.Site ON dbo.UserSite.SiteId = dbo.Site.SiteId
INNER JOIN dbo.TaskUserSites ON dbo.UserSite.UserSiteId = dbo.TaskUserSites.UserSiteId
INNER JOIN dbo.Task ON dbo.TaskUserSites.TaskId = dbo.Task.TaskId
INNER JOIN dbo.TaskRun ON dbo.Task.TaskId = dbo.TaskRun.TaskId
INNER JOIN dbo.RunDocument ON dbo.TaskRun.RunId = dbo.RunDocument.RunId
INNER JOIN dbo.PDFDocument ON dbo.PDFDocument.DocumentId = dbo.RunDocument.DocumentId
INNER JOIN dbo.RunDocumentVerificationResult ON dbo.RunDocument.RunDocumentId = dbo.RunDocumentVerificationResult.RunDocumentID
INNER JOIN dbo.Systemcode ON dbo.RunDocumentVerificationResult.Status = dbo.Systemcode.ID
```

[EstimatedTime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sNjB.png)

**Procdure Code is**

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[status] 
as
begin
begin transaction
declare @usersiteid bigint 
declare @runid bigint 
declare @TestedFiles int 
declare @TaggedFiles int 
declare @UnTaggedFiles int
declare @PassedFiles int
declare @FaildFiles int 
declare @Name varchar(500)
declare @VerificationEndDate datetime
declare @RootPageURL varchar (1024)
declare @status table ( Name varchar(1000) , Urlrootpage varchar(2000) ,Testedfile int , TaggedFiles int , Untaggedfile int ,passedfiles int , faildfiles int,VerificationEndDate datetime,rootpageurl varchar(1024) )
declare @domain table (name varchar(1000) , urlrootpage varchar (2000) )
if (1=2)
begin
select 'n' Name  ,'r' Urlrootpage  ,1 Testedfile  ,1 TaggedFiles  ,0 Untaggedfile  ,0 passedfiles  ,0 faildfiles,GETDATE() VerificationEndDate ,'r' rootpageurl where 1=2
end
create table #status ( Name varchar(1000) , Urlrootpage varchar(2000) ,Testedfile int , TaggedFiles int , Untaggedfile int ,passedfiles int , faildfiles int,VerificationEndDate datetime,rootpageurl varchar(1024) )
set @usersiteid = (select min (UserSiteId) from vw)
set @runid = (select max (runid) from vw where usersiteid = @usersiteid)
while @usersiteid is not null 
begin
set @TestedFiles   = (select (count ( distinct documentid )) from vw where UserSiteId=@usersiteid and runid=@runid  ) 
set @TaggedFiles = (select (count ( distinct documentid )) from vw where istagged=1 and UserSiteId=@usersiteid and runid=@runid)  
set @UnTaggedFiles =(select (count ( distinct documentid )) from vw where istagged=0 and  UserSiteId=@usersiteid and runid=@runid)
set @PassedFiles =(select (count ( distinct documentid )) from vw where Status<>1 and DocumentId not in (select DocumentId from vw where status =1) and UserSiteId=@usersiteid and runid=@runid)
set @FaildFiles = ( select (count ( distinct documentid )) from vw where Status=1 and UserSiteId=@usersiteid and runid=@runid)
set @Name = (select distinct name from vw where UserSiteId=@usersiteid)
set @rootPageUrl = (select distinct RootPageURL from vw where UserSiteId=@usersiteid)
set @VerificationEndDate = (select max(distinct VerificationEndDate) from vw where UserSiteId=@usersiteid and RunId=@runid)
insert into @status ( Name, Urlrootpage  , Testedfile  , TaggedFiles  , Untaggedfile  ,passedfiles  , faildfiles ,VerificationEndDate   ) values 
(@Name,@RootPageURL,@TestedFiles,@TaggedFiles ,@UnTaggedFiles,@PassedFiles,@FaildFiles,@VerificationEndDate)
set @usersiteid = (select min (UserSiteId) from vw where UserSiteId > @usersiteid) 
set @runid = (select max (runid) from vw where usersiteid = @usersiteid)
end
insert into @domain select UserSite.Name , Site.RootPageURL from UserSite inner join Site on UserSite.SiteId=Site.SiteId where UserSiteId not in (select UserSiteId from vw)
insert into @status select name,urlrootpage,0,0,0,0,0,null,0 from @domain
select Name,Urlrootpage,Testedfile,TaggedFiles,Untaggedfile, passedfiles,faildfiles from @status 
end
If (@@Error <> 0)   -- Check if any error
  Begin          
     rollback transaction       
  End 
else 
    commit transaction  
 return
```

Comment: If SQL server is installed at your machine - then it looks like your network bandwidth is bottleneck in this particular case.

Comment: So many things wrong. * Your database is tiny. Seriously. * 4 seconds on your machine indicates SERIOUS Problems already. * other maching an unqualified long time - really? Put a number there. But 270k not too large rows do not take 4 seconds to load. Unless you talk seriously underpowered mobile phone or something like that.

Comment: please add the select statement for your view and attach an execution plan

Comment: Read only your necessary column from table. Not asterisk.

Comment: @ayman2000, Let's start here: EXPLAIN ANALYZE <long_query_here>. Let us know what the analysis comes back as and then we can talk about optimizing it. It's tough to say what needs fixing if that's unclear

Comment: For such a tiny database and such a simple query, I would expect millisecond performance. I would suspect that you have failed to index properly.

Comment: @HLGEM, I agree. Image is saying that indexing missing. Indexing is needy

Comment: you mean i use indexed view?

Comment: I believe that he means that you need indexes on your tables. For example, are the tables defined with primary keys and do the foreign keys (where necessary) have indexes defined on their columns?

Comment: @ayman2000 add index for your tables, like id maybe?

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions read this link, it will clarify you and use EXPLAIN ANALYZE <your_query_here>

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind... if you're selecting without any `WHERE` clause then you're returning all of the rows. SQL Server can handle and process millions of rows very quickly. However, just moving that data across the network and displaying it on your screen can be very time consuming. This would also match with the issue that you're having where you see it taking substantially different amounts of time on two different machines.

Comment: i use this table as a source for Procedure i will put it`s code in the question

Answer (score 0):

I would do a little test to find out if it is actually, as suggested, the network bandwidth that causes your query to be slow, or, better said, to look like it's slow. Append a limit-statement to your query and run it, like LIMIT 10. So while the whole query will execute, only the 10 first rows will be sent, and if the network is your bottleneck, it should now be very fast. If it is still that slow, your machine's sql server probably has very little memory to use, so it can't fit the whole result in, and your local sql server is probably configured to use more memory, so it executes faster. In this case, giving your sql server more memory should fix the problem. This should be no problem at all, since, as already mentioned in the comments, your database is actually very small, so the currently used memory will be very small too.

If your network connection turns out to be the bottleneck, you need to decide if, and why, you need all the results to be sent at once. I can't really help you on that one, since I don't know what the application is supposed to do with the data. But probably you should either do some aggegration in the database, or only send a small part of the data over the network.